# Table with data from Json array, how to add multiple child rows

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, datatables-1.10

I have a html table with rows and child rows that are filled with data from a json array.
The problem I'm having are :
- The objects in the json array may or may not contain several object arrays, which need to be added as a child row.
- I can't get the array of child objects (interactions) out of the main object
An object of the json array is given below.

So far, I've managed to fill the table rows with data. I can also fill one child row, but only with data from the root of the object.

```
json object:
[
    {
        "name": "XXXXXXX",
        "firstName": "XXXXXXX",
        "contactnr1": "+123456789",
        "wrapup": "WRAPUP",
        "agent": "SUMO",
        "date": "05/02/2019 10:10:30",
        "totalAttempts": "2",
        "interactions": [
            {
                "agent": "SUMO",
                "interactionAlertStart": "02-05-2019 22:04:30",
                "interactionStart": "02-05-2019 22:04:32",
                "interactionCallStart": "02-05-2019 22:04:38",
                "interactionCallEnd": "02-05-2019 22:05:04",
                "interactionWrapupStart": "02-05-2019 22:05:16",
                "interactionWrapupEnd": "02-05-2019 22:05:16",
                "interactionEnd": "02-05-2019 22:05:26",
                "interactionType": "XXXXX",
                "interactionDuration": "54 s",
                "queue": "XXXX",
                "wrapup": "WRAPUP 1",
                "dnis": "tel:+123456789"
            },
            {
                "agent": "SUMO",
                "interactionAlertStart": "02-05-2019 22:10:29",
                "interactionStart": "02-05-2019 22:10:36",
                "interactionCallStart": "02-05-2019 22:10:52",
                "interactionCallEnd": "02-05-2019 22:11:00",
                "interactionWrapupStart": "02-05-2019 22:11:12",
                "interactionWrapupEnd": "02-05-2019 22:11:12",
                "interactionEnd": "02-05-2019 22:11:14",
                "interactionType": "Callback",
                "interactionDuration": "37 s",
                "queue": "YYYY",
                "wrapup": "WRAPUP 2",
                "dnis": "tel:+987654321"
            }
        ]
    },
```

++++++++++++++++++++++
javascript:

```
// function for formatting row details
function format (d) {
    // 'd' is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
                '<tr>' +
                    '<td>Agent:</td>' +
                    '<td>Datum:</td>' +
                    '<td>Contactnr:</td>' +
                    '<td>' + d.queue+ '</td>' +
                '</tr>' +
                '<tr>' +
                    '<td>Contactnummer:</td>' +
                    '<td>' + d.interactionStart+ '</td>' +
                '</tr>' +  
                '<tr>' +
                    '<td>TotaalPoging</td>' +
                    '<td>' + d.interactionEnd+ '</td>' +
                '</tr>' +
            '</table>';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        'ajax': {
            'url': 'http://127.0.0.1:8088/campaigns/contacttable?orgName=xxx&campaignId=yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy',
            'dataSrc': ''
        },
        'columns': [
            {
                'className': 'com-table',
                'orderable': false,
                'data': null,
                'defaultContent': ''
            },
            {'data': 'name'},
            {'data': 'firstName'},
            {'data': 'contactnr1'},
            {'data': 'totalAttempts'}
        ],
        'order': [[1, 'asc']]
    });
});
```

So to conclude: I want to dynamically add the data from the interactions as child rows. An object can have multiple interactions, only one interaction, or no interction.
My current javascript code is below the json array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well, you want to build the table based on this `interactions` array. I would start processing it. I recommend you to using the [`.map()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) method to create an array of rows.

```
 function processResponse(res){
  var interactions = response[0].interactions;

 // If no interactions, you may to return a single row

 if(!interactions || interactions.length === 0){
      return '<tr><td>No interactions to display.</td></tr>'  
 }

 var interactionsRows = interactions.map(function(interaction){
      return '<tr>' +
            '<td>Agent:</td>' +
            '<td>Datum:</td>' +
            '<td>Contactnr:</td>' +
            '<td>' + interaction.queue+ '</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr>' +
            '<td>Contactnummer:</td>' +
            '<td>' + interaction.interactionStart+ '</td>' +
        '</tr>' +  
        '<tr>' +
            '<td>TotaalPoging</td>' +
            '<td>' + interaction.interactionEnd+ '</td>' +
        '</tr>'
 });

 // Concatenate the rows into one string
 return interactionsRows.join();
}
```

Once I processed the response, I just need to concatenate it in the table.

```
 document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = processResponse(response)
```

See the snippet code working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xkh7j1rb/2/).

Note you should use the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) to manipulate HTML elements in a [better way](http://www.grauw.nl/blog/entry/475) instead to inject strings using `.innerHTML`. It's easier using JQuery.

Comment: Hello, this worked for me.
Thanks for the response and the note.